# Remove Modules in MVC 5 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an ASP.NET Mvc 5 application with Owin Authentication.

I use my own Roles and Users managers include on my service layer.

I know the application would be slightly faster if I remove some of the modules.

I identified the following modules

```
  <remove name="AnonymousIdentification"/>
  <remove name="FileAuthorization"/>
  <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule"/>
  <remove name="OutputCache"/>
  <remove name="PassportAuthentication"/>
  <remove name="Profile"/>
  <remove name="RoleManager"/>
  <remove name="ScriptModule-4.0"/>
  <remove name="ServiceModel"/>
  <remove name="Session"/>
  <remove name="UrlAuthorization"/>
  <remove name="WindowsAuthentication"/>
```

I am not sure if this is completely correct ... Is it?

Which of these modules is not safe to remove?

Comment: I'm not convinced you should remove Session, do you not want to use Session at all?

Comment: this also smells a little of micro optimisation. Do you have any evidence that removing these speeds up the application?

Comment: Yes, Session I will not remove ... Not sure about ServiceModel and OutputCache ... The rest I don't know.

Comment: I am not sure if the optimization is so small as you mentioned ... But I know that with Owin they remove FormsAuthentication so I wonder what other modules there are and do we need them?

Comment: @MDMoura - The default OutputCache implementation of MVC5 is excellent. It is possible that your website is tons slower without it.